# How to filter/search NSOutlineView without NSTreeController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

When I use an NSTableView, i can filter the items ont he table by using a NSArrayController.

I've created a simple NSOutlineView with 3 columns and I have it working with code (no bindings).
How do i setup a simple search/filter like you would normally have when you use a NSTreeController and bindings?

Unlike the way i usually do it with a Controller, how can this be done programitically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the outline view, just like any table view, is just displaying the data it received from its data source. If you want to perform a search, you need to perform the search yourself on your data source, and then update the outline view accordingly.